# Grails: Returning parameters from a taglib

Tags: grails, taglib

How do I return values from a taglib that has been called in a controller action such that it automatically retains the full type structure of the values setup in the taglib?

I can use the `out <<` approach but this returns strings or array of strings.

I have tried to use a `[]` mapping as used transfer a set of values at the end of an action to its view.

I have also tried a `return` statement again unsuccessfully - besides I need to return more than one set of values.

-mike

Comment: The `returnObjectForTags` may work but depending on what you are really trying to do it may be that a tag lib is the wrong thing altogether here.  Can you describe what it is you are doing with the tag lib?

Comment: I've tried to use the returnObjectForTags with a tag - but cannot get to work yet. Perhaps a service is a better option. Here is the taglib:

Comment: It isn't really clear what you are trying to do but there is nothing in your description that suggests that a tag lib makes sense.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest to use taglibs to process logic outside views, but there are some exceptions. For that purpose, the best practice is to user a service.

Answer (score 7):

from the top of the documentation http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#tagReturnValue

```
class ObjectReturningTagLib {

  static returnObjectForTags = ['content']

  def content = { attrs, body ->
    someValue()
  }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to return an ArrayList of selected instances of a domain model and also the size of the array. I am using a taglib in order to modularize some code that has successfully created this ArrayList in an controller/action.

Comment: That sounds like something that should probably be in a Service.

Comment: @Scott Perhaps a service is a better option - not sure of the difference with a taglib. The taglib has a series of ,.where' calls to the dB. I've had to abbreviate things below. The return value is a ArrayList of PublishedShr instances that I pass on to a view from the action:` def getPubVidList = {attrs, body->
  def currOrganId = attrs["visitorOrgan"]
  def queryMKP = PublishedShr.where {
   videoId in pubMkLstV
  }
  def pubMkLstP = queryMKP.list()
  def pubMkLstTotal = queryMKP.count()

  return pubMkLstP
    } // end getPubVidList`

Comment: I'm trying to use the taglib/returnObjectForTags as suggested. I am getting the ArrayList back but it doesn't cast it as a PublishedShr list which it what I need. Have shown the return in the above comment - struggling with the comment formatting apologies.

Comment: @Jeff I also have placed this into a service as suggested - having defined the service at the top of the taglib.

Here is the call in the taglib:
 
def getPubVidList1 = {attrs, body->
  def currOrganId = attrs["visitorOrgan"]
           
  def pubVids =  pubVidsService.getPubVids(currOrganId)
 
  return pubVids.pubMkLstP
}

I'm getting the error: 'Cannot get property 'pubMkLstP' on null object' - any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think this could solve your problem

```
package com.campaign
import java.util.*;
class UserDetailsTagLib {
def springSecurityService
static namespace = "jft"
#here we are defining that this getPrincipal and getArrayListAsObj tag used to return      object
static returnObjectForTags = ['getPrincipal','getArrayListAsObj']
 #this tag will return obj
def getPrincipal = {
    return springSecurityService.principal
}
# this tag is used to return the array list of string
def getArrayListAsObj = { attrs , body ->
  ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
  arrayList.add("C");
  arrayList.add("A");
  arrayList.add("E");
  arrayList.add("B");
  arrayList.add("D");
  arrayList.add("F");

  return arrayList

}
```

}

Comment: I have tried the above but still get a string list returned from the taglib. Here is the call in the controller:  `def pubMkLstP = getPubVidList(visitorOrgan: currOrganId)`  Not sure whether you intended me to include a version of the 2nd taglib getAppConfigData - I added a modified version without success anyway:  ` def getAppConfigData = { attrs , body ->
  out << (pubMkLstP.appConfig.configData."${attrs.key}")?.encodeAsHTML()
 }`. replacing the principal value with my value.  Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: in above given answere, i  have declare two tag. first is getPricipal that is used to get principal object from session and return object. and second tag is getAppConfighData that is another tag and it don't return out it just write the given k value in the response.

Comment: I am now creating the ArrayList in the taglib - an array of model instances. When I return it to the controller/action it does not cast it correctly.

Trying to print the ArrayList in the action I get a "No signature of method (SLF4JLog)" error.

It has successfully returned the ArrayList but as list of strings.

The return : `return pLst`

The call is: `def pLst = getPubVidList(visitorOrgan: currOrganId)`

I have added getAppConfigData not sure what I'm doing in truth - the out line is: `out << (pLst.appConfig.configData."${attrs.key}")?.encodeAsHTML()`

-mike

Comment: anand - I've tried this and it is not working. 

But I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly. 

I have simply cut and pasted the getArrayListAsObj tag as it is - but perhaps I need to modify it for my purposes?

Should I invoke the getArrayListAsObj in the action and pass through the object?

Otherwise how does the getArrayListAsObj effect the returned object?

Comment: have you also pasted :  static returnObjectForTags = ['getArrayListAsObj'] line in your tag file

Comment: anand - Yes - I've tried to use a Command Object, PubLst, in the controller - with one field:

  `PublishedShr pubId`

 Then placed the ArrayList from my query in the tag into it - using:

 `def pQueryLst = queryMKP.list()
 def pubList = pQueryLst.toList()
 def pLst = []
 for (iPl in pubList){ pLst.add( new PubLst( iPl)) }`

Returning this to the controller:

 `return iPl`

But it still cannot see the returned list correctly in the controller when printing - here are the lines:

 `def pLst = getPubVidList(visitorOrgan: currOrganId)
 log.debug(" userShrController pubMkLstP FOUND: ", pLst)`

Comment: `import java.util.*;` you must be kidding

Answer (score 0):

I understand your problem. If you want to have the Intellisense on the var you got from a taglib, the only thing you can have is this (it's a little redundant)

In a gsp for example, if you have a TagLib with namespace myTaglib:

First call the action of your taglib to set the value of a var:

```
<myTaglib:person var="currentUserFromTaglib" />
```

Where the `person` tag in the `myTaglib` is just for this purpose:

```
def person = { attrs ->
        this.pageScope."$attrs.var" = new Person(name:'Giuseppe', surname:'Iacobucci')
    }
```

After this, you need to write:

```
<g:set var="currentUser" value="${currentUserFromTaglib as Person}"/>
```

And include in you gsp:

```
<%@ page import="your.package.Person" %>
```

After that, in the gsp `currentUser` is recognized as type `Person`.

In a controller, you simply call the `myTaglib` and cast the result like so:

```
def myvar = myTaglib.person() as Person
```

Obviously if you need more a complex object as I read from your comments, then create a plain UI object with all information you need inside and do the same trick.